# Swift AVPlayer continuously loads when trying to play url video file

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, avplayer

I am attempting to play a video file from a youtube url. I have created the AVPlayer and linked the url to the player. The player opens when I click the button, but the video player just shows the file continuously loading. I have changed the App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads on the plist.

Heres the code:

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {


    let movieId = "xLCn88bfW1o"
    let path = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(movieId)")
    let video = AVPlayer(url: path!)
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    videoPlayer.player = video

    present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
        video.play()
    })

}
```

[image: Loading Video Player]

EDIT: I've also tried by using the URL for sharing the video; https://youtu.be/xLCn88bfW1o.

Answer (score 2):

The url you are using is not the url to the video, it is the url to a webpage which has the video embedded. There are tools out there that can help you get the actual url of the video file.

For example: **[YoutubeDirectLinkExtractor](https://github.com/devandsev/YoutubeDirectLinkExtractor/blob/develop/README.md)**

> YoutubeDirectLinkExtractor allows you to obtain the direct link to a YouTube video, which you can easily use with AVPlayer. It uses type safety and optionals to guarantee that you won't crash while extracting the link no matter what. There are popular alternatives, which use more straightforward and risky approach, though:

**Use extracted video link with AVPlayer:**

```
let y = YoutubeDirectLinkExtractor()
y.extractInfo(for: .urlString("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsQvAnCGxzY"), success: { info in
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: info.highestQualityPlayableLink!)!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player

self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player!.play()
}
}) { error in
print(error)
}
```

Comment: When I go to install the pod file I get `[!] Unable to find a specification for YoutubeDirectLinkExtractor` in the terminal

Comment: What’s your Swift & project version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the video file's direct URL to `AVPlayer` (not a Youtube website URL)

**For example:**

```
let path = URL(string: "https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")
```